# PHP Variables with undefined values from HTML form

Tags: php, is-empty

Okay so I have a script which is basically like an order form. However my only input options are radio buttons. When I run my script, I noticed that it turned back errors. Instead I would like it to display and empty field. The page posts back to itself and it updates a box I left blank on the bottom before submission. After submission details are filled in from a multitude. I also used a two dimensional array if that makes any difference. So my problems are with empty variables in the forms. I was not able to fix this and I think it might be the way I'm using it. I get an undefined index error for the variables that receive the data. In this case `$settype` and `$differentype` come out as errors since they are defined to be whatever was in the textbox. I thought that by using `empty()` I could eliminate that issue. I did not approach it correctly of course. Can anyone give me some guidance here? Thank you.

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="order.php">
    <input type="radio" name="set" value="1" /> 1
    <input type="radio" name="set" value="2" /> 2
    <input type="radio" name="set" value="3" /> 3
    <input type="radio" name="different" value="a" /> a
    <input type="radio" name="different" value="b" />
    <input type="radio" name="different" value="c" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $settype = $_POST['set'];
        $differentype = $_POST['different'];
        if ($settype == '1' && $differenttype =='a'){
            $order = $field[0][1];
        }
        if (empty($settype) && empty($differenttype)){
            $order = "";
        }
    }
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php print($order); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Joseph Silber thank youfor fixing my code.

Comment: You're missing a closing PHP tag (bafore `<table>`), and `differenttype` is missing the `$`.

Comment: In my actual code this it has the $ and it has the closing tag.

Comment: So I added it to the code posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your input submit ? like this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />`

EDIT 1: You should have a default radio button selected value like

```
<input type="radio" name="set" value="1" checked="checked"/> 1
<input type="radio" name="different" value="a" checked="checked" /> a
```

Comment: yes it's in that format.
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="login">

Comment: It is not in your code. i suppose it is just a typo. Also if it is `name="submit1"` so your code should be `if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {`

Comment: my original code does have submit1. Everything else works fine. In fact no errors display when I just open the file using the WAMP server. However when I press submit without selecting any radio button, I get an error that $settype and $diferenttype have an undefined index.